# What would the technical term be for this technology?

Tags: technology

A phone (if I base the story on Earth) or a datapad (If I base the story in the Star Wars galaxy) that allows the user to feel the texture and surface of things that appear on the screen. What would be a good technical term for this type of technology?

Answer (score 12):

The simple term is Haptic Technology - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology

We're not very far down that road and you could probably spice it up, since it currently implies some kind of mechanical component generating the feedback, and the technology taken to its extreme would require something far more sophisticated, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I also hear the term "Tactile" used to describe this technology.

http://discovermagazine.com/2015/june/17-hooked-on-a-feeling

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Though links can provide the same information, they are not stable over long time, so it is advised to put the most of the content in the answer for future reference, and provide the link as supporting information.

Comment: @L.Dutch I like the answer `haptic technology` above, but I just wanted to add that I've seen the word `tactile` used as well. The link is just an example of that word being used to describe the technology. Even if the link breaks, the rest of the answer should stand by itself.

Comment: then write a comment, if you goal is to comment

Comment: @L.Dutch The question was just asking for one word, so my answer is pretty short here. I didn't mean to leave a comment.

Comment: The question was put on hold for good reason. While i would normally agree that this answer is very much on the short side, i think for this question, the answer is complete (and imho correct) and would hardly be improved by providing a longer text.